# Iterating through a column in blade.php file

Tags: php, html, if-statement, iteration

I'm trying to figure how to iterate through this table which shows monthly records provided by different facilities within any one month.

As it is, every record from each facility has a month associated with it, but I want to make it so that there only one month record, followed by the next month displaying in the same way and so on.

I've been told to use an if statement to iterate through the month column to determine the number of rows one month record should cover, but I'm confused regarding the syntax, any suggestions?

This is the table code I'm working with atm:

```html
   <table id="table2" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover display" >
                                                      {{-- Beginning of headers --}}
                                                      <thead>
                                                        <tr class="text-center">
                                                            <th>Month</th>
                                                            <th>Grade</th>
                                                            <th colspan="3">Volume (m<sup>3</sup>)</th>
                                                          </tr>
                                                          <tr class="text-center">
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th>Received</th>
                                                            <th>Milled</th>
                                                            <th>Balance</th>
                                                          </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                        
                                                     {{-- End of headers --}}
            
                                                       {{-- Beginning of data --}}
                                                       @foreach ($grades1 as $g)
                                                       <tbody class="text-center">
                                                           <tr class="text-center">
                                                              <td rowspan="100">{{$g->yr_mm}}</td>
                                                              <tr>
                                                                  <td>{{$g->grade}}</td>
                                                                  <td>{{$g->vol_received}}</td>
                                                                  <td>{{$g->vol_milled}}</td>
                                                                  <td>{{$g->vol_balance}}</td>
                                                              </tr>
                                                           </tr>
                                                       </tbody>
                                                       @endforeach
                                                       {{-- End of data --}}
            
                                                </table>
```